# How do I create a pipe between two processes in Guile?

Tags: process, scheme, pipe, guile

I want to create two process in Guile and send the output (stdout) from one of them as input (stdin) to the other.

Using the following example, how can this be done?

```
echo "foo bar" | wc
```

Output:

```
1       2       8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this using `open-output-pipe`:

```
(let ((p (open-output-pipe "wc")))
  (display "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.\n" p)
  (close-pipe p))
```

This is equivalent to `echo "The quick brown fox jumps over the the lazy dog." | wc` (including `echo`'s implicit newline because I'm that particular, lol).

There is, of course, an `open-input-pipe` analogue. Read the [Pipes](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Pipes.html) section of the Guile manual for more details.

Comment: This does not answer the question, and there are no examples anywhere close to it either on the manual page you cited.

Comment: @Daniel It is equivalent to `echo "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog." | wc`

Comment: apologies, I get it now! Thanks!

Comment: @Daniel I normally don't edit posts without something substantive to change, but in this case I think a little added explanation didn't hurt. ;-)

Comment: would it be possible to extend the example to a `generate some data | grep something in it | sed something more` kind of command instead, with multiple pipings. Guile's posix commands accept arguments in different/unexpected ways, and it is fairly hard to find useful/comprehensive docs & examples to them